# Method Overloading (and reduction) with Java Generics

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, overloading

I have to create a logger for my object oriented programming class and I am having difficulty with method overloading and Java generics. I am almost certain that the logic in my methods is okay. However, my instructor is asking for us to call the writeLogMsg method to only be called once in one method. I need help doing this, because I'm relatively unfamiliar with generics, and have tried to research this for a while with very little progress. These methods are meant to print out the logger message with whatever value(s) given by the console or calling program.

```
 public void logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg){

    writeLogMsg(getMsgLvlString(msgLvl) + msg);
}

public <T> void logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg, T val){

    writeLogMsg(getMsgLvlString(msgLvl) + String.format(msg, val));
}

public <T,T2> void logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg, T val, T2 val2){

    writeLogMsg(getMsgLvlString(msgLvl) + String.format(msg, val, val2));

}

public <T,T2,T3> void logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg, T val, T2 val2, T3 val3){

    writeLogMsg(getMsgLvlString(msgLvl) + String.format(msg, val, val2, val3));

}

public <T,T2,T3,T4> void logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg, T val, T2 val2, T3 val3, T4 val4){

    writeLogMsg(getMsgLvlString(msgLvl) + String.format(msg, val, val2, val3, val4));

}
```

Comment: You don't need generics for what you are doing there: since the parameters of `String.format` are `String, Object...`, you can simply use `Object` instead of `T`, `T1`, `T2` etc. And for that matter, you can just have `logMsg(Message msgLvl, String msg, Object... vals)`. There is a slight performance hit to using the variadic form instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 arg overloads; that is balanced by the convenience of writing 1 method instead of multiple overloads.

Comment: varargs to the rescue

Comment: Also, since you're learning, what do msgLvl and msg mean? I assume it means "messageLevel" and message. Wouldn't it be much clearer if the variables were named "messageLevel" and "message", then? Why is message of type String, and messageLevel of type Message? If it's a message level, then the class should be named "Level" or "MessageLevel", not Message. This might sound picky, but it's absolutely critical to have readable, maintainable code. Your methods, on the other hand, could be named "log()". It's obvious that what you log is a message. And if it isn't, then it should be named logMessage

Comment: @AndyTurner I need to be able to log messages up to 4 variables...I'll still be able to do that with the solution you gave?

Comment: @Stef you will be able to log any (practical) number of variables.